# Pinging default gateway on a Linux virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, ethernet, ping, mac-address, icmp

I have two question about the network. I started to ping my router from my Linux virtual machine and I have intercepted these ICMP frames. I noticed that the destination MAC address is not my router MAC address and it's not even my host MAC address

The first question is therefore, who this MAC address belongs to?

The second question is about the frame. I noticed that the frame type is Ethernet II but I use WiFi and this frame is not a frame which describes Ethernet connections, so why I intercept Ethernet frame in Wi-Fi?

Comment: Please let us know what type of virtual machine are you using: KVM/QEMU, virtualbox, vmware?

Comment: I'm using virtualbox

Comment: What network type are you using in the virtual box? and at what point are you intercepting the frame?

Comment: I'm using NAT and I'm intercepting frame after ping request